# Event Trigger in SpreadJs

Tags: jquery, spreadjs

How could I make click(events) on the basis of cell position in spreadJs.
Ok, I know to change certain Css properties and get the cell value.
But, I need to trigger click function dynamically.... Say Something like "sheet.getCell(5,5).click()" as in jquery, but I'm unable to do that and stuck. Thanks in advance if any solution or advice.

Comment: Thank you for using SpreadJS.   Can you please explain why do you need to capture the click event of the cell.   SpreadJS has one Click event for the whole control and then it passes you the information about the cell being clicked.   this is more efficient than allowing potentially thousands of click events.    More explanation of why you need this would help us guide you in the right direction.   regards.   http://spread.grapecity.com

Comment: I need to this for automated testing purpose

Comment: I see.   Our team has a Selenium driver for testing SpreadJS.   please contact our support at http://spread.grapecity.com and we can help you.  The alternative is in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the Click event at the sheet level and in the event arguments get the row and column identifying the cell you need

[CellClick Event](http://sphelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/SpreadJSWeb/webframe.html#JavascriptLibrary~GcSpread.Sheets.Events~CellClick_EV.html)

hope this helps.